# what's the difference of return true or false here?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, javascript

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;  // return true;
});
```

what's the difference for this form submission function between return `false` and `true`?

Comment: return true; is the "default" - it will just continue. If you put return false;  then it exits the functions and tells the caller FALSE and stops. TRUE to not stop.. you see. Nobody uses return true in this case. But using return false; is good if you want a click to stop doing its normal behaviour for example. Like in your submit will do alert-- but stop after and not send data..

Comment: @ppumkin: I would not say that `return true` is the default. Having no `return` statement will return `undefined`. More correct would be that if the return value is any other than `false`, the submit event is processed normally.

Comment: Hmm. yea thats why i s said in quotes "" . But by definition a boolean only has 2 states. so if its not false its true. And this is tested when the function ends by the caller. so if undefined is translated to true.. then True is the "default" value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you return `false` from the submit event, the normal page form POST will not occur.

Answer (score 3):

`return false`, don't do the form's default action. `return true`, do the form's default action.

---

It's also better to do

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Almost. You forgot `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, returning false stops the event from "bubbling up". If you want the full details, take a look at the API documentation for `bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/bind/.

> "Returning false from a handler is equivalent to calling both .preventDefault() and .stopPropagation() on the event object."

Answer (score 1):

```
return false;  // cancel submit
return true;   // continue submit
```