# What is difference between using onclick return functionality and not using it?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, onclick, return

```
<script>
function doAlert() {
  return true; // what happens if function returns true
  return false;// what happens if function returns false 
}
```

with return 
    without return

Here is my HTML and javascript code. I have two checkboxes and for both of them doalert event is fired when clicked. For the with return part I want to know the differences when the function return true and when the function returns false. And I also want to know the differences between with and without returns. what is the difference ? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978274/whats-the-difference-of-return-true-or-false-here

Comment: How do you add the listener? `onclick=` or `addEventListener` ?

Comment: with return <input type="checkbox" onclick="if(doAlert())return;" /><br/>
without return <input type="checkbox" onclick="doAlert()" />

Comment: In this case there is no difference (and not sense in code)

Answer (score 2):

There is differrence if you use `onclick="return func()"`

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return doSomething()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
  return false;
}
</script>
```

In this case, you avoid the default action of checkbox. (In fact, the click don't have any effect and the checkbox is still unchecked)

**UPDATE**

in your case

```
return ;
```

returns simply `undefined` that don't have any effect on the event flow.
So there is no difference with any other return not strict equal to false.

Comment: I am afraid that the scenario is different form my problem

Comment: well.. then I pray you to explain your problem and show us your code :)

Comment: is there any difference between return (boolean value); and only return; ?

Answer (score 0):

if the function returns true then the code behind parts will gets executed and postback occures.

let me explain you. If i have username and password field. on submit button i write function that weather username and password fields are blank or not. if one of the field is blank i want to stop submit process so i write return false and asked user to enter blank field. if both are filled properly then i write return true as my validation parts get successfull and tell that now i can proceed with the server side function executing.